# How to use Rmarkdown to write academic paper based on LaTeX Template

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

How to use R markdown to write academic paper based on the LaTeX template not available in R studio R markdown template.

I want use R Markdown to write academic paper based on the LaTeX template for Computer Science Proceedings from Springer available [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs/conference-proceedings-guidelines). I downloaded the file. It contains the following files:

- LNS_Sample.tex
- lincs.csl
- samplepaper.tex
- spincs04.bst

What I did: I created a new Rmarkdown file and saved it in the same location where I saved the above files. I wrote the YAML header as shown below and included the template. But, when I knitted the document, I only saw the contents in the template file (`LNS_Sample.tex`) appear in the PDF. Anything I type after the YAML header does not appear in the generated PDF. Only the contents in the LaTeX template appear. How can I use the template in R markdown?

```r
---
title: "Sentiment Analysis with Domain Specific"
output:
  pdf_document:
    template: LNS_Sample.tex
---

## I write sample text here , but it does not show
```

Comment: The template is not going to work because it's not a template designed for pandoc. You might be able to just change the documentclass option to use their `.csl` file.

Comment: @Marius , please how to change the documentclass as you suggest?

Comment: It is usually easier to work in Sweave-style Rnw files instead of Rmd files.  They are basically LaTeX with the addition of code chunks, instead of a completely different language.